# Magento : Mobile Theme is Not Always Loading

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, rwd-theme, mobile

We use following settings to load mobile theme to mobile users:

[image]

This is Matched expression:

```
(iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|Pre|Palm|Googlebot-Mobile|mobi|Safari Mobile|Windows Mobile|Android|Opera Mini|mobile)|(!iPad|Silk|Kindle|Xoom|SCH-I800|Tablet)
```

When we test website from our phone - all types, it always works fine.

But we use visitor screen recording, on that one for every 7th visitor we see that it's loading desktop theme for mobile user.
Not sure if it's just there recording bug, or it really sometimes loads incorrect theme.

It's happening for same phones we use - iphone 6s, 7 (we can see by iOS version, screen resolutions ,etc)

What can be problem?